# Run c# console application using shellExecute

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, console-application

I have c# console application (Net framework 4.5, visual studio 2010 express). I can run this app by using cmd and its work normally. But with some very important reason I need run this app from other app that write on the c++. I have tried to run c# app by using ShellExecute, CreateProcess, WinExec. It's always crash and don't run at the same machine where I launched it before by using cmd. Is there still are any ways to start this c# app. Or need I compile/assemble this c# app with some special way?
Uppdate
example:

METHOD 1

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};  
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);   
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;  
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;  
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;  
ShExecInfo.lpFile = "C:\\PATH\\To\\THE\\APP.exe";  
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = szParameters;  
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;  
ShExecInfoFlash.hInstApp = NULL;  
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfoFlash);  
WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfoFlash.hProcess,INFINITE);
```

Method 2

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi; 
char bff[512]; 
memset(&si,0,sizeof(si)); 
si.cb=sizeof(si); 
if(!CreateProcess(NULL,szParameters,NULL,NULL,0,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi)) 
{ return TS_METHOD_ABORTED;} 
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,INFINITE); 
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess); 
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

And it's crashed always with the same way. It's told me that something unexpected happened and propose me to send report to the MS.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to execute the program from C++?

Comment: A C# program is never shy about throwing an exception.  You should not be shy to take advantage of that and actually **display** the exception.  Which requires you writing an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event.  Log or show the e.ExceptionObject.ToString() value.  You'll see the exception message and the way things turned out bad from the stack trace.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't get exception from c# app. I get exception when i try to run c++ program. And this is standard windows exception "oops something wrong, do you want send a report to the MS". And when i try to run some other console .exe app (from other vendors) with same way, c++ app just run other app without any exception.

Comment: Erm, your code to start a program is C++ code.  I give up.

Comment: What happens if you manually double-click or run the C# executable yourself.  Does it run as you expect?  Also, does the C# executable have any special permissions it requires to run, meaning, does it need to be invoked as a specific user, or have any esoteric security demands?  What OS are you trying to invoke the C# application on, and finally, do you have the correct target .Net framework installed on the machine that you're trying to invoke the application on?

Comment: it's run yourself as I'm expect. No spec permission, no spec users, no security. I have tested c# app at the XP, vista, 7. Yes, .Net was installed without it c# program does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done what you are trying to do in c++ in a long time, but I did it recently in c#. I know this is half an answer, so sorry in advance for that. Does ShellExecute in c++ (or any of the other methods) give you the ability to set the working directory of the program you are launching? I've found that sometimes without setting this, the program being launched will think that it is running in a system folder, and as a result it may be unable to load resources because the relative paths are wrong.

Hope it helps.

Edit:

It appears [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does have what you are looking for.

Now that an example was posted, from above:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};  
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);   
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;  
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;  
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;  
ShExecInfo.lpFile = "C:\\PATH\\To\\THE\\APP.exe";  
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = szParameters;  
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;  
ShExecInfoFlash.hInstApp = NULL;  
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfoFlash);  
WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfoFlash.hProcess,INFINITE);
```

First, I recommend trying to launch another program you KNOW should work, like notepad.exe.

Next, like I said originally, set the working directory to match the exe.

```
ShExecInfo.lpFile = "C:\\PATH\\To\\THE\\APP.exe";  
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = szParameters;  
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = "C:\\PATH\\To\\THE";
```

Comment: if the other application crashes, then the C++ app probably found the C# executable.

Comment: It may have found the c# exe but that c# app may have its working directory set to the one of the c++ app or even the system directory

Comment: Yeah Man You Right! I almost love you.